# Extend Hash class

Tags: ruby

I need to create my own class that extends Hash and append the additional method to insert to hash my own class variables.  Something like this:

```rb
   class MyHash < Hash
     def initialize
       super
       @local = 0
     end

     def append_my_data(my_data)
       @something@[my_data.id] = my_data
     end
   end

   d = MyHash.new
   d.append_my_data(some_var)
   p d[10]
```

What do I need to put instead @something@ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`self[my_data.id] = my_data` should do the trick. See http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_self.html.

Comment: i know this old but im trying to make the same thing but i cant understand why the id though?